# For loop seems to become infinite

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

// DEFINITION FOR THE PRICES. CHANGE/REMOVE if needed. Currently can be used for testing
#define pepsi 2.00
#define l_tea 1.50


// Menu function prototype for testing
// TODO: Replace with actual menu fucntion
void menu();
void inquire();
void calculate_price();
void order();

float total_price;
float price_per[3];

// Required for the Inquire function. **total_menu** can be moved inside function. Keep variable **choice** as is. DO NOT REMOVE.
// TODO: Change **total_menu** variable value to ACTUAL value
int choice[3] = {0,0,0};
int total_menu = 2; // <<<<<<<<<<< CHANGE

int main()
{
    inquire();
    order();

    return 0;
}

void inquire()
{
    char cont;

    // Start by giving instructions
    printf("Max 3 drinks. Input in NUMBER.\nChoose your drink(s):\n");

    // Implementation of menu function. Change name as seen fit.
    menu();

    for (int i = 0; i + 1 <= 3; i++)
    {
        // Ask for response
ask:
        printf("\n\n >>> ");
        scanf("%d", &choice[i]);

        // Check if in menu
        if ((int)choice[i] > total_menu)
        {
            printf("\nNot in menu. Please choose again!");
            goto ask;
        }
        printf("%d", i);
        // Ask if user wants to continue
        // Y for Yes, N for No.
        if (i + 1 < 3)
        {
            printf("\nDo you want to continue? (y/n) >> ");
            scanf("%s", &cont);

            switch (cont)
            {
                case 'y':
                    printf("\nChoose your drink %d: ", i + 2);
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    i = 4;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("\nChoose your drink %d: ", i + 2);
            }
        }
    }

    // Testing array implementation. Delete before final program
    for (int i = 0; i + 1 <= 3; i++)
        printf("\n%d) %d", i+1, choice[i]);
}

// Menu definition FOR TESTING. Replace with actual menu function
// TODO: REPLACE with actual MENU FUNCTION
void menu()
{
    printf("1) Pepsi \t RM%.2f\n", pepsi);
    printf("2) Lemon Tea \t RM%.2f", l_tea);
}

// Calculate price FOR TESTING. Replace with actual calculate function
// TODO: REPLACE with actual CALCULATE FUNCTION
void calculate_price()
{
    total_price = 0.00;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        switch(choice[i])
        {
            // CASE BASED ON MENU
            case 1:
                price_per[i] = pepsi;
                total_price += pepsi;
                break;
            case 2:
                price_per[i] = l_tea;
                total_price += l_tea;
                break;
            default:
                total_price += 0;
                break;
        }
    }

}

void order()
{
    char cont;

    calculate_price();

    printf("\n\nTotal price -> RM%.2f:\n", total_price);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("\tItem %d -> RM%f\n", choice[i], price_per[i]);

    printf("\nInsert Money? (y/n)");
    scanf(">> %s <<", cont);

    // No more testing needed.....
}
```

With the above code my for loop in inquire function seems to go into a infinite loop if I type 'y' once. The only way to break away is to type 'n' or exit the program. I've spent more time on this then I would like to confess. I did have a working version of it but I probably meddled with something leading to this.

I need some help please.

Comment: Thank you for posting a question, and for including a main() function.  Please whittle this down to a smaller example that is a [Compilable, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Thank you!

Comment: step through using your debugger

Comment: Few general tips, don't use gotos in your code in unnecessary places, usually it makes the code harder to understand (goto ask can be replaced with continue).
Also you use scanf with "%s" to get a string, but you save it in a variable with a type of char (only one character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char cont;
...
scanf("%s", &cont);
```

`%s` scanf modifier scanf for an array of characters which get's terminated by a null character. You specified the second argument of `scanf` function as a pointer to memory only with one single character. I would highly discourage scanning for user input of arbitrarily length using scanf, as it's easy to get stack overflow and out of bound array access, as it happens in your case. `scanf` just writes to memory at addresses `(&cont)+1`, `(&cont)+2` and so on, causing undefined behaviour to happen. That's why *always* specify the lenght of the string inside the `%s` scanf modifier. So you can do this:

```
char cont[512];
scanf"%511s", cont);
```

if your intention is to scan up to 511 (not 512, strings are null terminated, you need one more character for the '\0', so 511) characters from the user.
You can do this:

```
char cont;
scanf(" %c", &conf);
```

if your intention is to scan for a single character inputted from user ignoring leading white-space character.

It would be good to read about `scanf` modifiers `%s` and `%c`, documentation can be found for example on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). And never type `%s` in `scanf`, always `%<number>s`.

Comment: Thanks, yep, the problem was %c, actually I tried using it From the get go, but the input part was always skipped so I switched to %s. It really weird you have to use " %c" to get it work. Also I removed the goto statement and used continue as instructed. I know how bad the goto statement is, our lecturer insists on using it though. Actually he left a few requirements for the project, one being use a goto statement. I'll use it elsewhere where it's less complicated.

Answer (score -1):

@user1930693. It seems clear that you're wrongly scanning (reading) the user input to decide whether to continue or not. You can change `scanf("%s", cont)` or `scanf(">>%s<<", cont)` by `scanf("%c", &cont)` which properly matches your initial declaration of `cont` (`char cont`)